# OpenGL glTexImage2D cube map and width/height parameters

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, shadow

I am trying to setup shadow mapping in OpenGL using cube maps so I can do shadows for point lights.

The following throws a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` at me:

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    GLCALL(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, GL_FLOAT, 0));
```

According to the docs, it is probably because of this:

```
GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if target is one of the six cube map 2D image targets and the width and height parameters are not equal.
```

And I get if the width/height are different, they aren't really a cube, but when I have a screen resolution like 1920x1080 or any other resolution this is a problem.

Perhaps though I have missunderstod what to supply to the function call - isn't it the window width/height? What are the parameters supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Perhaps though I have missunderstod what to supply to the function call - isn't it the window width/height?

How in the world you think that the window resolution influences texture sizes is beyond me. You normally render shadow mapping depth maps using a framebuffer object, so the window dimensions are irrelevant.

> What are the parameters supposed to be?

For a cube map: The edge length of the cube map texture.

Comment: The framebuffer stores the final image (color map?) that will be rendered on the screen, hence shouldnt the texture size should match the window resolution aswell? Also, if not what sort of values are proper for the size of the cube map texture?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: There is not *the* framebuffers. There is *a* window framebuffer (with window size) and then there are user defined, framebuffer objects which are off screen, and which size is chosen by you. And no, even if the texture may be later rendered onto the screen (which isn't bound to happen) it may be largely distorted or just magnified or minified. So no, there's absolutely no forced correspondence between texture size and window size. As for shadow mapping: The texture size is arbitrary, and only depends on your demands for quality: Higher shadow texture resolution = higher quality